# For a Gaussian kernel, what is the sigma value, and how is it calculated?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

For a Gaussian kernel, what is the  sigma value, and how is it calculated?

$K(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j) = \exp{-\frac{\|\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j\|^2}{\sigma^2}}$ ?

Is it the covariance of the entire data set?

Comment: It's a parameter you will have to worry and tune.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I read about gamma coefficient in SVM in scikit-learn?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168014/where-can-i-read-about-gamma-coefficient-in-svm-in-scikit-learn) and also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/the-role-of-gamma-c-in-svm/124493#124493

Comment: So where does this parameter come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a Gaussian kernel, what is the  sigma value, and how is it
>   calculated?

As [@SleepWithStatistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/34623/sleepwithstatistics) pointed in the comments, it's not calculated: it's a parameter set prior to the kernel computations.

> Is it the covariance of the entire data set?

No, but heuristics exist to set the parameter based on the variance/covariance structure in the data.